# How can I hide the title in my user registration form?

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I am using LoginToboggan module. And I want to hide the title.

[image]

[image]

As you see in first picture "Log in" title is shown, and in second "Create new account" title is shown. How can I hide these titles?

Comment: Are you using panels? In that case its very easy, just check the rewrite title checkbox in your variant. Otherwise you can see if the $title is being set in a preprocess function or try to unset it in a preprocess page

Answer (score 2):

Use disable/hide title module. Alternatively, you can disable the title pretty easily with css. 
Another way is to disable the title using template.php using `drupal_set_title()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `hooK_form_alter`

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check the form_id
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') {
    // To hide the label
    $form['your_form_element']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
    // To alter the label
    $form['your_form_element']['#title'] = t('Your new title');
  }
}
```

put this code in custom module or if you want to use it in theme page then use mytheme instead of mymodule.

Or you can be do it by creating tpl file and comment title part code in tpl file